# Is there a way to limit only the download bandwidth on 1 torrent with Vuze

Tags: java, api, bittorrent, torrent, vuze

I'm using Vuze's (formerly known as Azureus) API to create a simulate a few BitTorrent scenarios.

Here is the API documentation : [JavaDoc](http://cdn01.vuze.com/site/dev/javadoc/Vuze_5701-19/)
I'm running multiple downloads, however I can't find a way to stop a download from downloading a file, while continuing to upload to other peers. the `Pause()` method in the [DownloadManager](http://cdn01.vuze.com/site/dev/javadoc/Vuze_5701-19/org/gudy/azureus2/core3/download/DownloadManager.html) class seems to pause even the upload.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to drill down from the UI. The per-torrent options can be found in `org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.views.TorrentOptionsView`, there is a `MAX_DOWNLOAD` static field, with a little help from the IDE of your choice you can follow the reference chain to  `org.gudy.azureus2.core3.download.DownloadManagerStats.setUploadRateLimitBytesPerSecond(int)`